Ubuntu 24.04 - System crashes when I connect a second screen
I have a laptop HP Victus 15 with a Nvidia GTX. Recently I upgraded my Ubuntu from 23.04 to 24.04. I installed the Nvidia driver version 560, however sometimes when I connect the laptop to a second monitor, both screens keep in black and the system crashes showing up an Oh no! Something has gone wrong message in both screens.

Here is the output of command inxi -SMG for PC specs:
System:
  Host: guarapo-PC Kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: Victus by HP Gaming Laptop 15-fb0xxx v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8A3E v: 35.43 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: F.16 date: 12/13/2022
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: nvidia
    v: 560.35.03
  Device-2: AMD Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Mobile Series]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: Quanta HP Wide Vision HD Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,radeon,vesa
    dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu,nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch resolution:
    1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~144Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: nvidia,radeonsi,swrast
    platforms: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: nvidia mesa v: 560.35.03
    renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650/PCIe/SSE2

